# .net core 3.1 upgrade error - Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'RSA'

Tags: token, identity, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

My code was perfectly fine in .net core 2.0  .  I have ported by code to .net core 3.1 .  Now I am getting the following error - "Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'RSA'.""  .  I googled and found an interesting [link][1] which was help full .  In this article there was particular mention of commenting out using "`using RSA`".  What is the implication of this ?

I found another good [link][2] which I used to build my code. The only issue with the sample is that it  loads the public key each time token validation happens . I want to load my public key for validation upfront and not when the token is validated.

Below is my pseudo code

```
public CustomAuthorize(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
         
              _publicKey = config[publickey];
              _issuer = config[issuer]; 
              _publicKeySignature = convertpemtoSecurityKey(config[pem])  // type SecurityKey         
              _tokenParams = TokenValidationParameters();
        }


public Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            
                return new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                {

                    ValidateIssuer = true,                 
                    Issuer = _issuer,
                    IssuerSigningKey = _publicKeySignature
                  }

            
       }
```

```
   public SecurityKey convertpemtoSecurityKey(String publicKey)
    {
         using RSA rsa = RSA.Create(); // if I remove 'using statement it works but not sure of the implications 
         rsa.ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo(Convert.FromBase64String(publicKey), out _);
         return new RsaSecurityKey(rsa);
    }
    
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
            {
    
                    var tokenHandler = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    
                    try
                    {
                        tokenHandler.ValidateToken(TokenParams, __tokenParams , out validatedToken);
                        return;
                    }
           }
```

Is it ok remove the "using"  while using RSA.Create()?  Is there any other workaround ?
[1]: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/1433
[2]: https://vmsdurano.com/-net-core-3-1-signing-jwt-with-rsa/